# Não abre nova aba usando window.open no Safari no celular

Tags: javascript

Olá. Estou com problema no window.open no Safari no iPhone. Eu criei uma Landing Page para visualizar, um pdf no navegador,e enviar catálogos por email. Ao clicar no botão não abre uma nova página com o pdf. O Chorme e firefox funciona.

Segue meu código

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.querySelector("#enviar").addEventListener('click', function() {
        document.querySelector(".mensagem-sucesso").style.display = "none";
        document.querySelector(".mensagem-erro").style.display = "none";
        document.querySelector(".mensagem-erro").innerHTML = "";



        let nome = document.querySelector("[name=name]")
        let mail = document.querySelector("[name=email]")
        let fone = document.querySelector("[name=phone]")
        let captcha = document.querySelector("[name=g-recaptcha-response]")

        let required = [nome, mail, fone];

        let hasInvalidField = required.filter(item => !item.value)

        if(hasInvalidField.length) {
            document.querySelector(".mensagem-erro").innerHTML = `
                ${hasInvalidField
                    .map(field => field.getAttribute('placeholder'))
                    .join(", ")} são obrigatórios`

            document.querySelector(".mensagem-erro").style.display = "block";
            return ; 
        }

        if(!validateEmail(mail.value)) {
            document.querySelector(".mensagem-erro").innerHTML = `Por favor, forneça um email válido.`
            document.querySelector(".mensagem-erro").style.display = "block";
            return ; 
        }



        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("nome", nome.value);
        formData.append("email", mail.value);
        formData.append("telefone", fone.value);
        formData.append("g-recaptcha-response", captcha.value);

        document.querySelector("#enviar").innerHTML = "Enviando..."
        document.querySelector("#enviar").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled")
        fetch('form-captcha.php', {
            method: "post",
            type:"json",
            body: formData
        }).then(response => {
            document.querySelector(".mensagem-sucesso").style.display = "none";
            document.querySelector(".mensagem-erro").style.display = "none";
            document.querySelector(".mensagem-erro").innerHTML = "";
            response.json().then(data => {
                document.querySelector("#enviar").innerHTML = "BAIXAR CAT&Aacute;LOGO"
                document.querySelector("#enviar").removeAttribute("disabled")
                if(data.status) {
                    document.querySelector(".mensagem-sucesso").style.display = "block"
                    //window.open("catalogo-nova-visao.pdf", "_blank")




window.open(url,'_blank', 'menubar=yes,location=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes')





                } else {
                    document.querySelector(".mensagem-erro").style.display = "block"
                    document.querySelector(".mensagem-erro").innerHTML = `${data.errorMessage} ${data.error ? `(${data.error})` : ''}`
                }
            })
        })
    });


});
```

Comment: Já verificou se não é alguma política de segurança do browser, ou alguma config do tipo adBlock que está bloqueando o popup?

Comment: Bug Parecido: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1350833#c9 ? Ou: https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/firefox-ios/issues/2481

Comment: não funciono as ideias citadas! :(

Comment: Qual iPhone vc tá usando?

Comment: testei no iPhone 6s, 5 e 7

Comment: O Chrome e Firefox que vc testou tb foram no iPhone ou no desktop?

Comment: Bom, eu testei aqui num iPhone antigo (4S) e ele usa Safari 9, que não é compatível com ES6 (`let`, arrow functions, template literals) e `fetch`... Converti tudo para o modo mais antigo usando `XMLHttpRequest` em vez de `fetch` e funcionou, porém o window.open não funcionou dentro do Ajax, só fora dele. A partir do iPhone 5 acho que já usa Safari 10 ou 11 (não tenho certeza) que acredito ser compatível com ES6 (tb não tenho certeza), só que mesmo assim acho que o window.open não abre dentro do Ajax. O navegador bloqueia.

Comment: Também tentei com ajax e não funcionou. só funciona o window.open, isso teste no mesmo modelos do iPhone.